# How would I check for gps spoofing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, gps, spoofing

I know there is no native api for that, but some hacks/tips would be appreciated. Anyone have any ideas? Is there a way to cross ref cell towers to gps location to see if your in, say 100m from your 'reported'  position.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  Only the device knows where it is, and your code only knows what the browser tells you.

Comment: Ain't that a whole bunch of lame. Thanks though.

Comment: Personally, I am quite pleased that a website cannot override my location preferences and determine exactly where I am.  Users should be in control of their devices and privacy.

Comment: Not an attack or anything, but why use gps services at all then? All these arGames have that one flaw. I'm just trying to deter cheating, that's all. Not trying to override anything, just check and return to the menu with a msg that cheaters are bad. Maybe I'll look into phonegap or something.

Answer (score 0):

... Not sure how to check for GPS "spoofing" exactly without knowing exactly how GPS spoofing would be done in code...

While I haven't coded any exact solution for this specifically, I would think the process might look like using known-good GPS data through something such as Kismet that performs Tri-Lateration & Comparing that data on the suspected device/codebase/GPS Data and comparing the results.

If there's some kind of difference in trilaterated location based on each dataset AND both data sets came from the same device/timestamp than it MIGHT be indicative of spoofing GPS data.

The specific code solution to doing this would require some fiddling but I don't think you'd need any API to do it aside from whatever GPS dongle maybe or access or a known-good GPS of whatever sort, in the device or otherwise in order to compare against. Just the physical known-good GPS and the right software.